# Android: How to setup spinner in toolbar from menu resource xml file?

Tags: android, menu, spinner, android-toolbar

I have attached the images below for the spinner that i need to setup in toolbar.

I have setup spinner using the string-array but that only displays text and not the colored dots besides each item. I have also tried setting up spinner using custom adapter but the dot is displayed besides the item after clicking it in the spinner dropdown.

Can anyone please help regarding this on how to achieve it? Any reference or link would be helpful. Also, Can we populate the spinner from any res/menu/ file ?

**Toolbar image before clicking on spinner**

[image: Toolbar image before clicking on spinner]

**After clicking on the toolbar spinner menu**

[image: After clicking on the toolbar spinner menu]

I have attached customer adapter code for reference if anyone requires

**Custom Adapter Code:**

```
public class HeaderStockOverviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HeaderSpinnerItem> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public HeaderStockOverviewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull HeaderSpinnerItem[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return getRowView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return getRowView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@NonNull
private View getRowView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_spinner_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    HeaderSpinnerItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getText());
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(rowItem.getColor());

    return convertView;

}

}
```

P.S: I am targeting devices of API 21 and above

Comment: Can you upload the code of your custom adapter?

Comment: added the custom adapter code

Answer (score 0):

```html
public class HeaderStockOverviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HeaderSpinnerItem> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public HeaderStockOverviewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull HeaderSpinnerItem[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return getRowView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_spinner_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    HeaderSpinnerItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getText());
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(rowItem.getColor());

    return convertView;
}

@NonNull
private View getRowView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_spinner_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    ImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    HeaderSpinnerItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    txtTitle.setText(rowItem.getText());
    imageView.setBackgroundColor(rowItem.getColor());

    return convertView;

}

}
```

Note : the row view and Drop down view should share the same views

Comment: Try to achieve the same view as the  getRowView to the getDropDownView may b that will solve your problem

Comment: I am already calling the same method from both getView() and getDropDownView(). Please check my adapter code

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I finally got the answer. It is in the **getView()** method and **getDropDownView()** method only.

1. The view that we return from `getView()` method is the view that is displayed when the item is selected.
2. The view that we return from `getDropDownView()` method is the view that is displayed for each item of dropdown when the dropdown menu is displayed.

So, in this case following are the modifications that I made in my custom adapter code.

```
public class HeaderStockOverviewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HeaderSpinnerItem> {

private LayoutInflater inflater;

public HeaderStockOverviewAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource, @NonNull HeaderSpinnerItem[] objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerTitleText);

    HeaderSpinnerItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    assert rowItem != null;
    txtTitle.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(rowItem.getText()));

    return convertView;

}

@Override
public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    return getRowView(position, convertView, parent);
}

@NonNull
private View getRowView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @Nullable ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_spinner_item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView txtTitle = convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    CircleImageView imageView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.icon);

    HeaderSpinnerItem rowItem = getItem(position);
    assert rowItem != null;
    txtTitle.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(rowItem.getText()));
    imageView.setImageResource(rowItem.getColor());

    return convertView;

}

}
```